# Missing icon - How to add icons not available in the Xcode appicon template?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm working with Xcode 10.0 and I cannot update to Xcode 10.1 for various reasons. I need to include WatchApp icons required to submit the App (50x50 and 108x108) but these sets are not available in the template for 10.0, I suppose they have been added with 10.1. How can I include this icons manually even if there are no slots marked as 50x50 and 108x108 in my Xcode version?

I'm trying to add the icons directly into the icon set folder, the icons appear on Xcode but I see this warning...

`Warning: The app icon set "AppIcon" has 2 unassigned children`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try manually updating the Contents.json file.

Here's what mine looks like with all icons, you can use it as a base to add the missing sections in yours:

```
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "size" : "24x24",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "Icon-24@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "role" : "notificationCenter",
      "subtype" : "38mm"
    },
    {
      "size" : "27.5x27.5",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "Icon-27.png",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "role" : "notificationCenter",
      "subtype" : "42mm"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "Icon-29@2x.png",
      "role" : "companionSettings",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "Icon-29@3x.png",
      "role" : "companionSettings",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "Icon-40@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "role" : "appLauncher",
      "subtype" : "38mm"
    },
    {
      "size" : "44x44",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "Icon-44@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "role" : "appLauncher",
      "subtype" : "40mm"
    },
    {
      "size" : "50x50",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "Icon-50@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "role" : "appLauncher",
      "subtype" : "44mm"
    },
    {
      "size" : "86x86",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "Icon-86@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "role" : "quickLook",
      "subtype" : "38mm"
    },
    {
      "size" : "98x98",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "Icon-98@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "role" : "quickLook",
      "subtype" : "42mm"
    },
    {
      "size" : "108x108",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "Icon-108@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "role" : "quickLook",
      "subtype" : "44mm"
    },
    {
      "size" : "1024x1024",
      "idiom" : "watch-marketing",
      "filename" : "Icon-1024.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  }
}
```

Comment: By any chance do you know what should I write for the "Long Look 44mm" and what for the "Short Look 44mm" watch icons?

Comment: Hi @MatterGoal, I'm running into the same issue. Would you please post the complete JSON blocks that got this working for you?